# How do I minimize the number of array accesses

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

How do I reduce the amount of time the array is accessed, at the moment it accesses the array 2 times to find the largest number in a sequence of numbers provided by the user,

```
int i=0;
    int max = -1;
    int a_i = -1;

    for (i=0; i<length; i++)
    {   
    a_i = array(a,i);

    if (a_i > max) 
    {
    max = a_i;
    }

    return max;
```

full code [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3JcQm79q)

any help appreciated.

Comment: The code seems to access each element of the array only once, which is a complexity of O(n).  If the array is sorted, you can reduce the complexity to O(logn) by using a binary search.

Comment: @AdamLiss: Well, if it's sorted it's O(1) since the code is finding the maximum value in an array of values. However, this is not what the OP is asking. To be honest, I don't see what problem the OP is having, looking at the code (taking into account a missing `}`) I think it's only accessing the array once.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a brace ?

Comment: @Skizz Oops ... O(1) ... of course!  How embarrassing!  :-)

Comment: Did you even run this code? After fixing the missing brace, it correctly reports that each array element is only accessed once.

Answer (score 1):

- Short answer

you cant, you have to iterate over every item, considering you have no information about the array.

- Long answer

you can reduce the amount of access at reading, if you accept losing some time before

Using an array you need `O(n)` to insert (everyting) and `O(n)` to find the minimum

if what you really want is to reduce time spent in the find function,
you can use a [minimum heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29), you will have some overhead at insert `O(n log(n))` but you will only need a `O(1)` to search.

you could also sort the array before searching, this can be `O(n log n)`